# How to set and retrieve cookies in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

I have tried setting cookies in codeigniter like this, but not working don't know what is the problem

//setting cookie

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');

if($loaded_position == 'nativelocation' ){
    $this->input->set_cookie('nativelocation' , $request_place, '86400');
    //echo $this->input->cookie('nativelocation');              
}
```

//retrieving cookie

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$savedlocation =  array();
if( $this->input->cookie('addlocation_1') )  
{   
    $savedlocation[]= $this->input->cookie('addlocation_1') ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are setting a cookie called "nativelocation" but then you try to retrieve a cookie called "'addlocation_1", and there isn't one. Try:

```
if( $this->input->cookie('nativelocation') ){
   echo $this->input->cookie('nativelocation');
}
```

Also, know that when setting a cookie, you can not access it on the same "page" you'll need a page refresh, or access the cookie `$this->input->cookie('nativelocation')` on another page/controller.

Comment: hi one more soubt if we can set the $this->load->helper('cookie') in the controller or model constructor do we need to use the load helper code in all function. do we

Comment: you need to load the (any) helper in the desired function of the controller, or always auto load via config/file.php (can't recall exact file at the moment).